# Firebird JDBC update listener

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, listener, firebird

I need to develop app which could do this: user launches few copies of my app, in every copy there's one table with data from Firebird database. When user changes something in one copy of app, any other copies must immediately show the changed data. How to do it? I thought about some "UpdateListener", but couldn't find something similar in JDBC driver.
P.S. update tables every second isn't a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Firebird database system supports an [event mechanism](http://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/papers_presentations/Power_Firebird_events.pdf). In your database schema you can add triggers on UPDATE, INSERT and DELETE to post such events. The client applications can register an event listener and if there is a change they will be notified by the database.

Jaybird is the Firebase JDBC driver. It supports the Firebase events with the Events API. Here is a [detailed example](https://github.com/FirebirdSQL/jaybird/wiki/Jaybird-Events-API) for using the Firebird events with Java applications.

Comment: "*Unlike other database systems*" - Postgres and Oracle also support the even listeners for updates.

Comment: Ok, thank you, I updated my answer. I found the description of the PosgreSQL NOTIFY command here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-notify.html. But nothing for Oracle. Do you have a link?